# matomo content tracking not coming through to dashboard

Tags: matomo

I am not able to get content tracking working in Matomo 4.4.1.

Event tracking works fine, now I want to implement content tracking so data shows up in Behaviour > Contents.

I followed the manual and enabled content tracking so the current Javascript looks like this:

```
var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    _paq.push(["trackAllContentImpressions"]);
    (function() {
    var u="//matomo-test.nfshost.com/matomo/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '3']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
```

I enhanced various elements on my page with data-attributes such as `data-track-content` and `data-content-name`.

When I go to the Chrome Dev console and type in `_paq.push([‘logAllContentBlocksOnPage’])` I get an array of all the elements so this is also looking good.

Then, when accessing the website and clicking on a button or link that has the data-track-content attribute a request in the Google Dev Tools Network tab is fired just fine. The code snippeet below is is the debug content of such a request.

However, when I go to Matomo > Dashboard > Contents nothing is displayed. I only get “There is no data for this report”. My Matomo is set up to gather the data every 10 seconds but even if I wait nothing shows up. The date is set correctly so this is not the problem. There is just not any data :(

Any help on how to get content tracking working would be cool!

````
[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Website 3 tracker cache was re-created. [] {"class":"Piwik\\Tracker\\Cache","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Current datetime: 2021-09-17 08:50:49 {"date":"2021-09-17 08:50:49"} {"class":"Piwik\\Tracker","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CoreHome\Tracker\VisitRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\IntranetMeasurable\Tracker\RequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Actions\Tracker\ActionsRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Goals\Tracker\GoalsRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Ecommerce\Tracker\EcommerceRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\SitesManager\Tracker\SitesManagerRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PrivacyManager\Tracker\RequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: General tracker cache was re-created. [] {"class":"PrivacyManager","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Heartbeat\Tracker\PingRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PagePerformance\Tracker\PerformanceDataProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CustomDimensions\Tracker\CustomDimensionsRequestProcessor::manipulateRequest()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:49] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CoreHome\Tracker\VisitRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: DoNotTrack header not found [] {"class":"PrivacyManager","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Visitor doesn't have the piwik cookie... [] {"class":"CoreHome","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: The visitor was not matched with an existing visitor... [] {"class":"CoreHome","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\IntranetMeasurable\Tracker\RequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Actions\Tracker\ActionsRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: (this is not a Site Search request) [] {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Excluding parameters "gclid,fbclid,fb_xd_fragment,fb_comment_id,phpsessid,jsessionid,sessionid,aspsessionid,doing_wp_cron,sid,pk_vid,pk_cpn,pk_campaign,piwik_campaign,mtm_campaign,matomo_campaign,utm_campaign,utm_source,utm_medium,pk_kwd,pk_keyword,piwik_kwd,mtm_kwd,mtm_keyword,matomo_kwd,utm_term,mtmPreviewMode" from URL [] {"class":"Contents","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Action is a CONTENT, Action name = , Action URL = http://localhost/pageIntro {"type":"CONTENT","name":null,"url":"http://localhost/pageIntro"} {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Goals\Tracker\GoalsRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Ecommerce\Tracker\EcommerceRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\SitesManager\Tracker\SitesManagerRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PrivacyManager\Tracker\RequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Heartbeat\Tracker\PingRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PagePerformance\Tracker\PerformanceDataProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CustomDimensions\Tracker\CustomDimensionsRequestProcessor::processRequestParams()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CoreHome\Tracker\VisitRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Visitor IP (was: 84.179.163.142) has been anonymized: 84.179.0.0 [] {"class":"PrivacyManager","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\IntranetMeasurable\Tracker\RequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Actions\Tracker\ActionsRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: idaction_content_interaction = click [] {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: idaction_content_name = Merkzettel &gt; ausdrucken [] {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: idaction_content_piece = Button [] {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: idaction_content_target = Drucker [] {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Goals\Tracker\GoalsRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Ecommerce\Tracker\EcommerceRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\SitesManager\Tracker\SitesManagerRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PrivacyManager\Tracker\RequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Heartbeat\Tracker\PingRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PagePerformance\Tracker\PerformanceDataProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CustomDimensions\Tracker\CustomDimensionsRequestProcessor::afterRequestProcessed()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: New Visit (IP = 84.179.0.0) [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Following dimensions have been collected from plugins: idsite, profilable, user_id, visit_first_action_time, visit_first_action_time, visit_goal_buyer, visit_goal_converted, idvisit, location_ip, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visit_last_action_time, visitor_seconds_since_first, visitor_seconds_since_order, config_id, idvisitor, visitor_returning, visitor_seconds_since_first, visitor_seconds_since_order, visitor_count_visits, visit_entry_idaction_name, visit_entry_idaction_url, visit_exit_idaction_name, visit_exit_idaction_url, visit_total_actions, visit_total_interactions, visit_total_searches, , referer_keyword, referer_name, referer_type, referer_url, , location_browser_lang, config_browser_engine, config_browser_name, config_browser_version, config_client_type, config_device_brand, config_device_model, config_device_type, config_os, config_os_version, visit_total_events, visitor_localtime, visitor_localtime, visitor_seconds_since_last, visitor_seconds_since_last, config_resolution, config_cookie, config_flash, config_java, config_pdf, config_quicktime, config_realplayer, config_silverlight, config_windowsmedia, , visit_total_time, location_city, location_country, location_latitude, location_longitude, location_region [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Excluding parameters "gclid,fbclid,fb_xd_fragment,fb_comment_id,phpsessid,jsessionid,sessionid,aspsessionid,doing_wp_cron,sid,pk_vid,pk_cpn,pk_campaign,piwik_campaign,mtm_campaign,matomo_campaign,utm_campaign,utm_source,utm_medium,pk_kwd,pk_keyword,piwik_kwd,mtm_kwd,mtm_keyword,matomo_kwd,utm_term,mtmPreviewMode" from URL [] {"class":"Referrers","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Excluding parameters "gclid,fbclid,fb_xd_fragment,fb_comment_id,phpsessid,jsessionid,sessionid,aspsessionid,doing_wp_cron,sid,pk_vid,pk_cpn,pk_campaign,piwik_campaign,mtm_campaign,matomo_campaign,utm_campaign,utm_source,utm_medium,pk_kwd,pk_keyword,piwik_kwd,mtm_kwd,mtm_keyword,matomo_kwd,utm_term,mtmPreviewMode" from URL [] {"class":"Referrers","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Excluding parameters "gclid,fbclid,fb_xd_fragment,fb_comment_id,phpsessid,jsessionid,sessionid,aspsessionid,doing_wp_cron,sid,pk_vid,pk_cpn,pk_campaign,piwik_campaign,mtm_campaign,matomo_campaign,utm_campaign,utm_source,utm_medium,pk_kwd,pk_keyword,piwik_kwd,mtm_kwd,mtm_keyword,matomo_kwd,utm_term,mtmPreviewMode" from URL [] {"class":"Referrers","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Excluding parameters "gclid,fbclid,fb_xd_fragment,fb_comment_id,phpsessid,jsessionid,sessionid,aspsessionid,doing_wp_cron,sid,pk_vid,pk_cpn,pk_campaign,piwik_campaign,mtm_campaign,matomo_campaign,utm_campaign,utm_source,utm_medium,pk_kwd,pk_keyword,piwik_kwd,mtm_kwd,mtm_keyword,matomo_kwd,utm_term,mtmPreviewMode" from URL [] {"class":"Referrers","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: GEO: Found IP 84.179.0.0 location (provider 'geoip2php'): array (   'continent_name' => 'Europe',   'continent_code' => 'EU',   'country_code' => 'DE',   'country_name' => 'Germany',   'city_name' => 'Frankfurt am Main',   'lat' => 50.111,   'long' => 8.682,   'postal_code' => NULL,   'region_code' => '',   'region_name' => 'Hesse', ) [] {"class":"UserCountry","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: array (   'idvisitor' => '0c2756fcc3999c88',   'config_id' => '3c3e30bf4f81fba0',   'location_ip' => '84.179.0.0',   'idsite' => 3,   'profilable' => 0,   'visit_first_action_time' => '2021-09-17 08:50:49',   'visit_goal_buyer' => 0,   'visit_goal_converted' => 0,   'visit_last_action_time' => '2021-09-17 08:50:49',   'visitor_returning' => 0,   'visitor_seconds_since_first' => 0,   'visitor_seconds_since_order' => NULL,   'visitor_count_visits' => 1,   'visit_entry_idaction_name' => 0,   'visit_exit_idaction_name' => 0,   'visit_exit_idaction_url' => 0,   'visit_total_actions' => 0,   'visit_total_interactions' => 0,   'visit_total_searches' => 0,   'referer_keyword' => NULL,   'referer_name' => NULL,   'referer_type' => 1,   'referer_url' => '',   'location_browser_lang' => 'de-de',   'config_browser_engine' => 'Blink',   'config_browser_name' => 'CH',   'config_browser_version' => '93.0',   'config_client_type' => 1,   'config_device_brand' => 'AP',   'config_device_model' => 'generic desktop',   'config_device_type' => 0,   'config_os' => 'MAC',   'config_os_version' => '10.15',   'visit_total_events' => 0,   'visitor_localtime' => '13:45:35',   'visitor_seconds_since_last' => 0,   'config_resolution' => '1920x1080',   'config_cookie' => 1,   'config_flash' => 0,   'config_java' => 0,   'config_pdf' => 1,   'config_quicktime' => 0,   'config_realplayer' => 0,   'config_silverlight' => 0,   'config_windowsmedia' => 0,   'visit_total_time' => 0,   'location_city' => 'Frankfurt am Main',   'location_country' => 'de',   'location_latitude' => '50.111',   'location_longitude' => '8.682',   'location_region' => '', ) [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CoreHome\Tracker\VisitRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\IntranetMeasurable\Tracker\RequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Actions\Tracker\ActionsRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Inserted new action: array (   'idvisit' => '14',   'idsite' => 3,   'idvisitor' => '0c2756fcc3999c88',   'idaction_url' => '71',   'idaction_url_ref' => 0,   'idaction_name_ref' => 0,   'server_time' => '2021-09-17 08:50:49',   'idpageview' => 'DrZS1j',   'time_spent_ref_action' => 0,   'idaction_content_interaction' => '72',   'idaction_content_name' => '81',   'idaction_content_piece' => '77',   'idaction_content_target' => '82',   'idlink_va' => '616', ) {"action":"array (\n  'idvisit' => '14',\n  'idsite' => 3,\n  'idvisitor' => '0c2756fcc3999c88',\n  'idaction_url' => '71',\n  'idaction_url_ref' => 0,\n  'idaction_name_ref' => 0,\n  'server_time' => '2021-09-17 08:50:49',\n  'idpageview' => 'DrZS1j',\n  'time_spent_ref_action' => 0,\n  'idaction_content_interaction' => '72',\n  'idaction_content_name' => '81',\n  'idaction_content_piece' => '77',\n  'idaction_content_target' => '82',\n  'idlink_va' => '616',\n)"} {"class":"Actions","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Goals\Tracker\GoalsRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Ecommerce\Tracker\EcommerceRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\SitesManager\Tracker\SitesManagerRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PrivacyManager\Tracker\RequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\Heartbeat\Tracker\PingRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\PagePerformance\Tracker\PerformanceDataProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: Executing Piwik\Plugins\CustomDimensions\Tracker\CustomDimensionsRequestProcessor::recordLogs()... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:50] piwik.DEBUG: -> Scheduled Tasks: Starting... [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: 2021-09-17 08:50:50 matomo-test[99237]: starts for 1 2021-09-17 08:50:50 matomo-test[99237]: EXCEPTION: Handler::Handler: the listen descriptor is not a socket  [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: Finished Scheduled Tasks. [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: Next run will be from: 2021-09-16 12:26:55 UTC [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: Nothing to notice => default behaviour [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: End of the page. [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: <hr /><strong>Breakdown by query</strong><br/>Executed <b>2</b> times in <b>0.8ms</b>  (average = <b>0.4ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT idsite, url FROM matomo_site_url</pre>Executed <b>2</b> times in <b>1.2ms</b>  (average = <b>0.6ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT idsite, main_url as url FROM matomo_site</pre>Executed <b>6</b> times in <b>2.5ms</b>  (average = <b>0.4ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT * FROM matomo_custom_dimensions WHERE idsite = ?</pre>Executed <b>6</b> times in <b>3.1ms</b>  (average = <b>0.5ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT url FROM matomo_site_url WHERE idsite = ?</pre>Executed <b>1</b> time in <b>3.5ms</b>  <pre> UPDATE matomo_log_link_visit_action SET time_network = ?, time_server = ?, time_transfer = ?, time_dom_processing = ?, time_dom_completion = ?, time_on_load = ? WHERE idlink_va = ?</pre>Executed <b>6</b> times in <b>4ms</b>  (average = <b>0.7ms</b>) <pre> SELECT * FROM matomo_goal WHERE idsite IN (3) AND deleted = 0</pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>4ms</b>  (average = <b>0.6ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT option_name, option_value FROM `matomo_option` WHERE option_name LIKE ?</pre>Executed <b>12</b> times in <b>5.4ms</b>  (average = <b>0.5ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT login FROM matomo_access WHERE idsite = ? AND access = ?</pre>Executed <b>1</b> time in <b>6ms</b>  <pre>    INSERT IGNORE INTO `matomo_option` (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES (?, ?, ?) </pre>Executed <b>12</b> times in <b>6.1ms</b>  (average = <b>0.5ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT * FROM matomo_site WHERE idsite = ?</pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>7.1ms</b>  (average = <b>1ms</b>) <pre>   SHOW COLUMNS FROM `matomo_log_conversion`</pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>7.3ms</b>  (average = <b>1ms</b>) <pre>    SHOW INDEX FROM matomo_log_visit WHERE Key_name = ?</pre>Executed <b>10</b> times in <b>7.5ms</b>  (average = <b>0.8ms</b>) <pre>   SELECT `idaction`, `type`, `name` FROM matomo_log_action WHERE ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) OR ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) OR ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) OR ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) OR ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) </pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>7.5ms</b>  (average = <b>1.1ms</b>) <pre>  SHOW COLUMNS FROM `matomo_log_link_visit_action`</pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>8.4ms</b>  (average = <b>1.2ms</b>) <pre>   SELECT option_value, option_name FROM `matomo_option` WHERE autoload = 1</pre>Executed <b>4</b> times in <b>10.2ms</b>  (average = <b>2.6ms</b>) <pre>  UPDATE `matomo_option` SET option_value = ?, autoload = ? WHERE option_name = ?</pre>Executed <b>10</b> times in <b>11ms</b>  (average = <b>1.1ms</b>) <pre>    SELECT visit_last_action_time, visit_first_action_time, idvisitor, idvisit, user_id, visit_exit_idaction_url, visit_exit_idaction_name, visitor_returning, visitor_seconds_since_first, visitor_seconds_since_order, visitor_count_visits, visit_goal_buyer, location_country, location_region, location_city, location_latitude, location_longitude, referer_name, referer_keyword, referer_type, idsite, profilable, visit_entry_idaction_url, visit_total_actions, visit_total_interactions, visit_total_searches, referer_url, config_browser_name, config_client_type, config_device_brand, config_device_model, config_device_type, visit_total_events, visit_total_time, location_ip, location_browser_lang, last_idlink_va, custom_dimension_1, custom_dimension_2, custom_dimension_3, custom_dimension_4, custom_dimension_5 FROM matomo_log_visit WHERE visit_last_action_time >= ? AND visit_last_action_time <= ? AND idsite = ? AND config_id = ? ORDER BY visit_last_action_time DESC LIMIT 1</pre>Executed <b>1</b> time in <b>11.2ms</b>  <pre>    SELECT idlink_va FROM matomo_log_link_visit_action LEFT JOIN matomo_log_action ON idaction_url = idaction WHERE idvisit = ? AND idpageview = ? AND matomo_log_action.type = ?</pre>Executed <b>7</b> times in <b>11.6ms</b>  (average = <b>1.7ms</b>) <pre> SHOW COLUMNS FROM `matomo_log_visit`</pre>Executed <b>4</b> times in <b>19.6ms</b>  (average = <b>4.9ms</b>) <pre>  INSERT INTO matomo_log_visit (idvisitor, config_id, location_ip, idsite, profilable, visit_first_action_time, visit_goal_buyer, visit_goal_converted, visit_last_action_time, visitor_returning, visitor_seconds_since_first, visitor_seconds_since_order, visitor_count_visits, visit_entry_idaction_name, visit_exit_idaction_name, visit_exit_idaction_url, visit_total_actions, visit_total_interactions, visit_total_searches, referer_keyword, referer_name, referer_type, referer_url, location_browser_lang, config_browser_engine, config_browser_name, config_browser_version, config_client_type, config_device_brand, config_device_model, config_device_type, config_os, config_os_version, visit_total_events, visitor_localtime, visitor_seconds_since_last, config_resolution, config_cookie, config_flash, config_java, config_pdf, config_quicktime, config_realplayer, config_silverlight, config_windowsmedia, visit_total_time, location_city, location_country, location_latitude, location_longitude, location_region) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)</pre>Executed <b>6</b> times in <b>20ms</b>  (average = <b>3.3ms</b>) <pre>    UPDATE matomo_log_visit SET profilable = ?, visit_last_action_time = ?, visitor_seconds_since_order = ?, visit_total_time = ? WHERE idsite = ? AND idvisit = ?</pre>Executed <b>10</b> times in <b>38.5ms</b>  (average = <b>3.9ms</b>) <pre>   INSERT INTO matomo_log_link_visit_action (idvisit, idsite, idvisitor, idaction_url, idaction_url_ref, idaction_name_ref, server_time, idpageview, pageview_position, time_spent_ref_action, idaction_content_interaction, idaction_content_name, idaction_content_piece, idaction_content_target) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)</pre>Executed <b>10</b> times in <b>75.4ms</b>  (average = <b>7.5ms</b>) <pre>   connect</pre>Executed <b>253</b> times in <b>105ms</b>  (average = <b>0.4ms</b>) <pre>  SELECT option_value FROM `matomo_option` WHERE option_name = ?</pre> [] {"class":"Piwik\\Profiler","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: array (   'matomo_lang' => 'language=ZW4=',   'MATOMO_SESSID' => 'a9584809c1410c70a76f3352df6afa86', ) [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}

[2021-09-17 08:50:58] piwik.DEBUG: Time elapsed: 8.759s [] {"class":"Piwik\\Common","request_id":"40dff"}```
````